# Add Linq.Contains method To a Expression Func<Object,Bool>

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, expression, ef-core-2.2

I have a problem with that yellow part in the screenshot. I want if SelectedGroup is not empty. In addition to the terms added to that expression, add another condition. That's it.

```
c => SelectedGroup.Contains (c.CourseGroup.Id)
```

Select all those SelectedGroups that have their ID in that range. This query I wrote did not work. Error that gives is that it can not be translated into a SQL query. I have no idea to solve this problem. Help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEp0G.png)

And for more detail about my code - this is my code repository:

[enter link description here](https://github.com/MehdiSheykhveysi/Educational-website/blob/master/Site.Core/Infrastructures/Utilities/Extensions/IQueryableExtension.cs)

[enter link description here](https://github.com/MehdiSheykhveysi/Educational-website/blob/master/Site.Core/DataBase/Repositories/CourseRepository.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ride of the `combine` Func, it can't help you. You shouldn't compile your expression if you really intend to return a queryable.

What you could do is :

```
Expression<Func<Course, bool>> expression = c => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) || EF.Functions.Like(c.CourseTitle, $"%{Title}%")
        && c.IsDeleted == IsDeleted);

        switch (statusType)
        {
            case PriceStatusType.All:
                break;
            case PriceStatusType.Free:
                queryable = queryable.Where(expression).Where(c => c.CoursePrice < 1000);
                break;
            case PriceStatusType.Cash:
                queryable = queryable.Where(expression).Where(c => c.CoursePrice <= MaxPrice && c.CoursePrice >= MinPrice);
                break;
        }
        if (SelectedGroup != null && SelectedGroup.Any())
        {
            Expression<Func<Course, bool>> e = c => SelectedGroup.Contains(c.CourseGroup.Id);
            queryable = queryable.Where(expression);
            queryable = queryable.Where(c => SelectedGroup.Contains(c.CourseGroup.Id));


        }

        return queryable;
```

Also, I removed the Include because it's useless and should be used by the caller if it's needed.